# Programmatically Send Picture In Instagram with Hashtag Using API

Tags: android, instagram, hashtag, instagram-api

Is there anyway to send picture to user's instagram with HashTag?
I checked documentation and did not see any information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:...

[link](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/)